Help on Configuring LACP with Nexus 3000 and Proxmox
We recently acquired 5 new server nodes that will make up our new Production Proxmox VE Cluster.
We also acquired a set of 2 Nexus 3172T Switches and are in the process of configuring the Network interfaces on our Switches/Nodes.
We're having issues configuring LACP as the dedicated interfaces are suspended on both switches.
Here's the current config
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst

Frontend Interfaces:
description Management Interfaces for Nodes 1-5
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
  channel-group 1 mode active
  no shutdown

interface port-channel1
  description Management Port-Channel
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1
  spanning-tree port type normal

interface port-channel51
  description Stack Port-Channel
  switchport mode trunk
  spanning-tree port type network

port-channel1 carries both Vlan 1 and 20 (Ceph)

If you have a problem with the Promoix, that is off-topic here (you can ask about that on [sf]). On the Nexus port channel 1 interface and the member interfaces, you are only allowing VLAN 1, not VLAN 20. You can also try the port channel interface command,  no lacp suspend-individual. Some server vendors require that command on the Nexus.

Thank you, was not aware of that option.
The proxmox side seems fine and the issue seems to be mostly on the switch side.

Didn't configure vPC so that's probably the issue.
Will update this question with more info tomorrow from the office.

Normally, getting a suspend on the switch interface indicates a server configuration problem.

FYI, you start planning now to replace those Nexus switches as there will be no more software maintenance releases for them, and they are headed toward EoL.

Head of IT just purchased them, as refurbished .
They're running a 100k$ cluster.

It is generally not recommended to use VLAN 1 for anything if you are using other VLANs because of the chance to easily misconfigure something and provide it access to unintended network resources. Generally once you start using VLANs you should use a specific VLAN for everything unless you have no ability to do so (dumb equipment without VLAN tagging support). In such a case you should select a VLAN for those kind of devices or for the network they need to join and intentionally set it as the default/untagged VLAN on those interfaces.

As for the support for the switches, it should run through some point in 2027, I think. Probably fine. The bigger issue would be that for a $100k cluster, they are simply not fast enough. You want 40 or 100 gigabit switches for that much compute and storage (assuming you didn't just vastly overpay for old/slow servers). For a couple hundred more, you could get something like a N9K-C93180YC-EX with 25 gig and 100 gig ports. Still end of sale so very cheap, but at least much faster.

You didn't show the LACP feature being enabled. Other than that, the interface configuration must 100% match the port-channel. I've found it best to start with empty interfaces, define the port-channel, add the channel-group to the interfaces, and then go configure everything on the port-channel. (there are a few interface specific elements like description.) There should be log messages if there's a mismatch.
Here's how mine is setup...
! version 9.3(1) Bios:version 5.0.0 

feature lacp

vlan ...

no port-channel load-balance resilient

interface port-channel1
  description ...
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
  no lacp graceful-convergence
  port-channel port hash-distribution adaptive

interface Ethernet1/49/1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
  channel-group 1 mode active

interface Ethernet1/49/2
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
  channel-group 1 mode active

interface Ethernet1/49/3
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
  channel-group 1 mode active

interface Ethernet1/49/4
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 10
  switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
  channel-group 1 mode active

